# iterating through a string

Tags: python, string, loops

I'm exploring python and want to iterate through a string

```
mystring = '''1,"abc","abcde",1,2,3
              2,"zzz","zzzde",1,2,5
              3,"xyz","xyzde",4,3,2'''
```

This is a collection of three pairs of string and separated by a new line '\n'

Ideally I want to split it with '\n' and iterate through that array.

How can I do this in Python?

This is what I was thinking:

```
x = mystring.split('\n')

for aword in x
    print('\n' + str(aword[1]))
```

I want to be able to access each element of each line. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: You do exactly what you said: split on the newline and iterate through the resulting list (not array).  Just where are you stuck?  Post the code.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Python reads those enters as a newline. So using the built in python function split() we can create a list separated by "\n".

**Code**

```
mystring = '''1,"abc","abcde",1,2,3
              2,"zzz","zzzde",1,2,5
              3,"xyz","xyzde",4,3,2'''
mystring = mystring.split()
for i in mystring:
    pass
```